# How to set the progressbar with the chronometer in android?

Tags: java, android, timer, android-widget, android-ndk

I have learn how to get progressbar works with perticular task [from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

But i am using chronometer in my app. And based on that value i want to set the ProgressBar.

So how to do it. ?

I have made this thread to work.
Code:

```
// Start lengthy operation in a background thread         
    progressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {             
        public void run() {                 
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {                     
                mProgressStatus = doWork();                     
                // Update the progress bar                     
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {                         
                    public void run() {                             
                        progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);                         
                    }                     
                });                 
            }             
        }         
    });

    progressThread.start();
```

I know that i have to make task that continous return the int data to the progressStatus. But how to do it with chronometer that i dont know. So please help me for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Why i am getting negative for this question ?

Comment: whats wrong in this question ?

Comment: you should try to use sleep(1000);

Comment: What your doWork() method does? Could you please post the code of doWork()? The only thing I see here is a code snippet from the http://developer.android.com/... Maybe that's why someone gave you negative points..

Comment: @Serhiy: right now i am doing nothing with doWork();. But i want to implement the progressbar should be get progress with the cronometer value. So for that i want help. So how to set it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seem to be your doWork() method (as you mentioned in comment that there is nothing done in that method). As you can see progress of the progressBar depends from this method:

```
mProgressStatus = doWork();
```

Lets suppose that your cronometer is updating every second, so the progressBar will be full when 100 seconds will pass. To achive that, your doWork method should return increasing value of seconds passed, i.e 1,2,3...to 100. But returning that value only is not enough, because with your current code the progressBar will be filled instantly.
The most simple solution would be:

```
mProgressStatus = 0;
progressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {             
    public void run() {                 
        while (mProgressStatus < 100) {                                          
            // Update the progress bar                     
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {                         
                public void run() {                             
                    progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);                         
                }                     
            });
            mProgressStatus ++;
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000); // Thread.sleep() doesn't guarantee 1000 msec sleep, it can be interrupted before               
        }             
    }         
});

progressThread.start();
```

Hope this helps,
Serhiy.